# Ember.js - how do I get the width of an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I'm getting to grips with Ember.js but could do with some tips...

I'd like to create a view that is a **div** with a **ul** nested within it. Before rendering, I'd like to see how wide the parent **div** is and calculate how many **li**'s to add to the **ul** with a for loop.

Can you help suggest the best way to do this please as I'm struggling!

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

A way to determine the `width` of a `view` would be by hooking into the `didInsertElement`

```
App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({
  willInsertElement: function() {
    console.log(this.$().css('width'));
  },
  didInsertElement: function() {
    console.log(this.$().css('width'));
  }
});
```

For your use case is `willInsertElement` more relevant, because it will be called right before `didInsertElement` but the `width` is at this point still not yet calculated.

Here is a example [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ajabas/3/edit) to play with.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Cheers dude. I found out after posting my question that you can use jQuery on the element with didInsertElement - as it's now obvious that it doesn't exist on the page before this is called!

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing much about your code, here is a **very quick and basic example**. Hopefully it will give you some pointers and you can adapt it.

The idea is to use the `didInsertElement` event on the view, which is called when it has been inserted into the DOM, then you can get a JQuery object of that view's DIV with `this.$()`.

```
App.SomeKindOfView = Ember.View.extend({
  //-snip-
  didInsertElement: function()
  {
    this._super();
    var parentWidth = this.$().parents('div').width();
    //do some fancy caculation with parentWidth
    //then save the result on the View or Controller...
  }
  //-snip-
});
```

In the template you can have something like (since it is by default wrapped by a DIV:

```
<ul>
  {{#each item in controller}}
    <li>{{item.someContent}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Comment: Again, nice one. Using didInsertElement - as it's now obvious that it doesn't exist on the page before this is called! Incidentally, what's the purpose of the this._super()?

Comment: super calls the same function on the parent class. when extending Ember.View it doesn't really matter, but if you were extending a View which has its own didInsertElement hook, you'll have to call super for it to be executed too.